# Equivalence of atlases of vector bundles is an equivalence relation

Tags: differential-geometry, equivalence-relations, vector-bundles

I'm trying to show that equivalence between atlases of vector bundles is indeed an equivalence relation.

#### Definitions

Let $ V\subset \mathbb R^n $ be an open set and let $ F $ be a (real, finite dimensional) vector space.

For the purpose of this post define a *local vector bundle* as the product $ V\times F $.

If $ V_1\times F_1 $ and $ V_2\times F_2 $ are two local vector bundles, call a function $ f\colon V_1\times F_1\to V_2\times F_2 $ a *morphism* of local vector bundles if there exist two smooth (say, $ C^\infty $) functions $ \alpha_1\colon V_1\to V_2 $ and $ \alpha_2\colon V_1\to \hom(F_1, F_2) $ such that $ f(x,\eta) = (\alpha_1(x),\alpha_2(x)\eta) $.

If $ S $ is a set, call a pair $ (U,\phi) $ where $ U\subset S $ is a subset and $ \phi $ is a bijection from $ U $ to a local vector bundle a local vector bundle *chart* on $ S $.

Define now an *atlas* of local vector bundle charts on $ S $ as a collection $ \mathscr B $ of (guess what...) local vector bundle charts on $ S $ such that:

1. $ S = \bigcup_{(U,\phi)\in \mathscr B}U $;
2. for every pair $ (U_1,\phi_1) $ and $ (U_1,\phi_2) $ of charts of $ \mathscr B $ such that $ U_{12} = U_1\cap U_2\neq \emptyset $, the images $ \phi_1(U_{12}) $ and $ \phi_2(U_{12}) $ are local vector bundles and the composite of the mappings
   $$
   \require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
   \phi_1(U_{12}) @>{\phi_1^{-1}{\restriction_{\phi_1(U_{12})}^{U_{12}}}}>> U_{12} @>{\phi_2{\restriction_{U_{12}}^{\phi_2(U_{12})}}}>> \phi_2(U_{12})
   \end{CD}
   $$
   and
   $$
   \require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
   \phi_2(U_{12}) @>{\phi_2^{-1}{\restriction_{\phi_2(U_{12})}^{U_{12}}}}>> U_{12} @>{\phi_1{\restriction_{U_{12}}^{\phi_1(U_{12})}}}>> \phi_1(U_{12})
   \end{CD}
   $$
   are morphisms of local vector bundles.

The main definition is the following. Two atlases $ \mathscr B_1 $ and $ \mathscr B_2 $ are said to be *equivalent* (graphically, $ \mathscr B_1\sim \mathscr B_2 $) if their union $ \mathscr B_1\cup \mathscr B_2 $ is again an atlas.

I'm trying to show that, if $ \mathscr B_1\sim \mathscr B_2 $ and $ \mathscr B_2\sim \mathscr B_3 $, then $ \mathscr B_1\sim \mathscr B_3 $, where the $ \mathscr B_j $s are all atlases on a fixed set $ S $.

#### What I tried so far

Let $ (U_1,\phi_1\colon U_1\to V_1\times F_1) $ and $ (U_3,\phi_3\colon U_3\to V_3\times F_3) $ be charts respectively of $ \mathscr B_1 $ and $ \mathscr B_3 $ such that $ U_{13}\neq \emptyset $.

I tried to imitate the proof of the fact that equivalence of atlases smooth manifold is an equivalence relation, but things started to get messy. How to deal with all the $ \alpha_1 $ and $ \alpha_2 $s?

Comment: Show that every atlas is contained in a unique maximal one.

Comment: If $ \mathscr B $ is an atlas and a chart $ (U,\phi) $ is *compatible* with $ \mathscr B $ when it is compatible with every chart in $ \mathscr B $, I can let $ \mathscr V $ to be the set of all charts compatible with $ \mathscr B $, and then $ \mathscr V $ should be a maximal atlas (if we were working with smooth manifolds instead of bundles, it would be). But how do I show that $ \mathscr V $ is an atlas in the first place? I think that in this case, too, I have to show the same thing that I am already trying to prove here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** consider $(U_1,\varphi_1)\in\mathscr{B}_1,(U_2,\varphi_2)\in\mathscr{B}_2,(U_3,\varphi_3)\in\mathscr{B}_3$ charts on $X$ such that $U_1\cap U_2\cap U_3\neq\emptyset$. Of course $\mathscr{B}_1,\mathscr{B}_2,\mathscr{B}_3$ are atlases such that $\mathscr{B}_1\sim\mathscr{B}_2$ and $\mathscr{B}_2\sim\mathscr{B}_3$.

Comment: Mi fa ridere che io abbia postato qui pensando che di là a una domanda del genere nessuno mi avrebbe risposto, e niente, alla fine non mi ha risposto nessuno neanche qui per quindici giorni e alla fine sei arrivato tu:)

Comment: Ok, I suspected I had (not?) answered to the same question on matematicamente.it/forum, and the end of the day I receive the confirm of my though! ...and did I resolve your doubt? P.S.: it is better to avoid the Italian language here.

Comment: On the forum I was asking how limiting it would be to define a bundle atlas to be a collection of vector bundle charts all taking values in a local bundle $ V\times F $, where $ V\subset \mathbb R^n $ is open ($ n $ is fixed!). This question is different. I've just seen your hint, but I'm on holiday so I don't plan to take up this topic soon this week (if I were less of a liar: setting up the proof is a pain; I will surely do it, but not now). Anyway, can I pm you on the forum when I pick up this stuff again? If I recall correctly, I tried something similar, but I wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Don't worry: you can send me a PM on this topic. Don't forget to try to use my hint. O:)